# MySQL function: in clause HAVING query runs twice

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have written MySQL function which retrieves sum of database records.

```
SELECT id, myFunction(id) as price from myTable;
```

returns:

```
+———————+————————+
| id    |  price |
|  1    |    10  |
|  2    |    20  |
|  3    |    30  |
|  4    |    40  |
|  5    |    50  |
+———————+————————+
```

A problem occurs while I try to limit results to price BETWEEN 20 AND 40.

If I do it in HAVING CLAUSE, this function will be executed two times. First time while retrieving in SELECT myFunction, and second time near the HAVING PRICE.

Example:

```
SELECT id, myFunction(id) as price from myTable HAVING price BETWEEN 20 AND 40.
```

Is it possible to modify this query to one-time execute? Because of complicated calculating, it's bad idea to run this same operation twice.

Comment: What does `myFunction` do exactly?  If you are retrieving just the sum then why not use `SUM()` instead of `myFunction()`?

Comment: How do you know that it's being executed twice?

Answer (score 2):

You could try "materializing" the results with a subquery like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT id, myFunction(id) AS price FROM myTable) t
WHERE price BETWEEN 20 AND 40
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SUM(id) function instead of myFunction(id) because afterall you are just calculating sum of ids, use this query

SELECT id, SUM(id) as price from myTable WHERE price BETWEEN 20 and 40,

Always use having with groupby clause.

Comment: **@user2269315**, you basically reiterated my comment up above.